# Como saber si mi clave primaria esta como clave foranea en otras tablas en POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

Hola estoy usando POSTGRESQL, como puedo saber si una clave primaria de mi "Tabla A" esta como clave foranea en otras tablas como "Tabla B", "Tabla C", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El camino es buscar en la tabla `information_schema.table_constraints`, los constraints de tipo 'FOREIGN KEY'. Por ahí había encontrado una consulta que usaba esta y un par más de tablas de la metadata

Algo como:

```
select kcu.table_schema || '.' ||kcu.table_name as foreign_table,
       '>-' as rel,
       rel_tco.table_schema || '.' || rel_tco.table_name as primary_table,
       string_agg(kcu.column_name, ', ') as fk_columns,
       kcu.constraint_name
from information_schema.table_constraints tco
join information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
          on tco.constraint_schema = kcu.constraint_schema
          and tco.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
join information_schema.referential_constraints rco
          on tco.constraint_schema = rco.constraint_schema
          and tco.constraint_name = rco.constraint_name
join information_schema.table_constraints rel_tco
          on rco.unique_constraint_schema = rel_tco.constraint_schema
          and rco.unique_constraint_name = rel_tco.constraint_name
where tco.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
group by kcu.table_schema,
         kcu.table_name,
         rel_tco.table_name,
         rel_tco.table_schema,
         kcu.constraint_name
order by kcu.table_schema,
         kcu.table_name;
```

Dará un resultado similar a:

```
|foreign_table  |rel|primary_table|fk_columns  |constraint_name   |
|---------------+--+-------------+-------------+------------------|
|public.table1  |>-|public.table2|ch_other_id  |field_id_fk|
|public.table3|>-|public.table4|acc_table_id|other_id_fk |
```